# Subsequent logins failing in Azure Function

Tags: c#, function, azure, azure-active-directory, subscription

I have an interesting conundrum that I could really use some guru advice on.

I have a multi-threaded C# Azure Function that uses an application principal to log into the service manager endpoint and gather monitoring information across multiple subscriptions.  It works great … once!  On subsequent runs, 4 hours later, I log in, get a token (the same one while it’s live, I expect), setup a new HttpClient with the token header just like before and then try to access the endpoints.  Every one comes back “unauthorized”.

I've tried changing from static instances of my ApiHelper to ones initialized for each run in case one instance was overwriting another's token.  I am able to reproduce on my laptop with one instance, too, so it's not a threading thing.

The code to get the token is pretty simple:

```
        ClientCredential applicationCredentials = new ClientCredential(this.AADClientId, this.AADClientKey);
        resultobject = await this.AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.ResourceUrl, applicationCredentials);
```

As is the code to setup the client header:

```
        this.WebClient = new HttpClient();
        this.WebClient.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        this.WebClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
        this.WebClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        this.WebClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"application/json")); // ACCEPT header
```

I then pass the same webClient to every Task that gets monitors.

As I say, it works fine the 1st time all the way through.  The next time the Function executes, everything is unauthorized.  I guess my next step is to start creating test functions and drilling in on login tests, but would love it of someone can point out any obvious miss that might be causing this.

Comment: How is your function app triggered ? also are you using azure function v1, v2 ? Could you confirm while running the code locally that it acquires a new token on every run ?

Comment: Have your refresh your access token for at least 1 time for an hour in 4 hours ?